# TextView is not able to set ImageView

Tags: android, xml

I am new to Android. I am making a layout. I want to set textview below imageview, but I am not able to. When I drag the textview by myself below the image the RelativeLayout becomes matchparent. Please see my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/sample" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:text="sbxcdgdbc dhwe hdejd djhe  dqe "
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The background image is 500*350 pixel
[image]

Comment: Because the TextView is not on the same level of the ImageView. By the way, why did you put all those LinearLayouts? Not only they are bad for performances, they also clutter your design. By the way, The ImageView can be avoided, by using a **compound drawable** for the TextView, therefore increasing the performances a bit more.

Comment: @DerGolem At first i made it simple without thses much layouts but i faced error that's why i used these.

Comment: @DerGolem I have Updated my code. Even now it's not working

Comment: `android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"` should be `android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"`. Without the **+** sign. Otherwise, you are creating a new `imageView1` id.

Comment: who ever rated this question negative please try there in their project. then he will know that this question is programmatically right.

Comment: **Now**, that **you corrected the extra +**, it is.

Comment: @DerGolem i have tried that to ... see my code

Comment: Your picture shows what you get if you write **above** instead of **below**.

Comment: @DerGolem I want image in "CentralHorizontal & CentralVertical

Comment: @DerGolem Above is also not working its shows Exception and the image disappears

Comment: **NO**. The TextView has to get `layout_below="@id/imageView1"`. The ImageView should only have `layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Comment: @DerGolem Still it not working

Comment: Read my last comment.

Comment: @DerGolem I have tried that 2 ... the image comes in the center by layout_centerInParent="true" but the text is not coming below the image.

Comment: @DerGolem If you want the background image i can send it to you... then u will try

Comment: @AmarbirSingh First! change your 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` inside your relativelayout to: 
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: @Strider I don't want to do android:layout_height="fill_parent" because i have to put TabHost below this.

Comment: @Strider `fill_parent` is **deprecated**. use `match_parent`, instead

Comment: @AmarbirSingh The background image is ininfluent.

Comment: @DerGolem yeah, my bad, I normally use `match_parent` ,check my post. I don't know why I said `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/sample"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:text="sbxcdgdbc dhwe hdejd djhe  dqe "
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line `android:layout_below="@+id/rr"` to `android:layout_below="@id/rr"`. In the first version, you're saying here's a new ID. In the second version, you're referencing the ID so you don't need the +.

Comment: you also have that line in the linear layout between the text view and the above linear layout holding the image view. you should try fixing it (removing the +) from the middle linear layout and giving this layout an id. then set the below id to be this middle layout. so you'll have something like the second layout below rr and the textview below whatever id you give the middle linear layout

Answer (score 0):

If you have so simple layout you should use LinearLayout with param: orientation vertical. Then every new view will be add below earlier. Later you can use margin param to change space between views.

Comment: When i use LinearLayout i can't use "CentralHorizontal & CentralVertical Params"

Answer (score 0):

You can use different ways to achive your requirement

1. LinearLayout with Orientation vertical inside which the children can be a Textview and an ImageView.

> But the problem is its not the best way to use to different views for this.

2. You can go for any parent layout relative/linear with a child having one Textview containing a tag named as compound drawable and give the image.

> With this approach you can have a single image above, below, right or left of the textview. Which I belive a good approach.

Comment: could you please tell me the param to use in textview.

Comment: android:drawableEnd="@drawable/image_name"

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is to just show TextView below the ImageView, you should take LinearLayout with "vertical" orientation, see below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center|center"
android:background="@drawable/sample">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="sbxcdgdbc dhwe hdejd djhe  dqe "
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edited the answer according to your comment.

Comment: I want my image in the Center(Vertically & Horizontally) and Text below this image.

Comment: Ok to show Image in Center, add these two properties in parent LinearLayout , android:layout_height="match_parent"and add android:gravity="center|center"   ... Edited my answer according to your requirement, Please check

Comment: The background image straches to whole screen(match parent) by this code. the image is 500*350 pixel

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sample" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="sbxcdgdbc dhwe hdejd djhe  dqe "
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where i have to change in Relative,Image or Text.

Comment: @AmarbirSingh in your `TextView`

Comment: I want the image in the Center(Horizontally & Vertically) not on the top. see the image which i have uploaded.

Comment: @AmarbirSingh then add `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @hrskrs nope, he needs to change 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in his layout to: 
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: I want the imageview(ic_launcher) in the center not the background of relativelayout

Comment: @Strider I don't want to do android:layout_height="fill_parent" because i have to put TabHost below this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/sample">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
        android:text="sbxcdgdbc dhwe hdejd djhe  dqe "
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want it on the Top i just want image "CentralHorizontal & CentralVertical and the textview below this image

Comment: Can you post an image showing exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want ic_launcher in the center and text below this.